# Python how to do facebook wall post using graph api?

Tags: python-2.7, facebook-graph-api

i am trying to post a message into my wall using facebook graph api. I have my access_token. I have tried in my browser using following URL.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?message="Hii friends"&access_token=xxxxxxxxxx
```

But message is not posted. So i couldn't solve this problem. Finally i want to use this URL inside urllib2.urlopen()

Please Help

Comment: you need to do a POST call. what you are trying to do is GET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently got posting to facebook to work like so:

```
import requests

face_token = 'your_token'
post = 'Your Post wowzers'
post.replace(' ', '+')
requests.post("https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed/?message=" + post + "&access_token=" + face_token)
```

Comment: Shoul not do post.replace, because you have to encode all special characters in the URL query string. You can do `import urllib.parse` and then `qs = urllib.parse.urlencode({"message": post, "access_token": face_token})` and finally `requests.post("https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed/?%s" % qs)`

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with the graph api like this:

```
import facebook
def main():
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token='your_user_access_token', version='2.8')
    #if version 2.8 show error use 2.6
    attachment =  {
        'name': 'Link name'
        'link': 'https://www.example.com/',
        'caption': 'Check out this example',
        'description': 'This is a longer description of the attachment',
        'picture': 'https://www.example.com/thumbnail.jpg'
    }

    graph.put_wall_post(message='Check this out...', attachment=attachment, profile_id='your_page_id')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If you leave the profile_id blank, it will default to your profile. In the attachment dictionary, you can leave the extra fields that you don't need. First you need to install fackbook-sdk:

```
pip install facebook-sdk
```

Comment: following is the github link of facebook-sdk: there is example of attachment usage. [link](https://github.com/eleith/python-sdk/blob/master/src/facebook.py)

Answer (score 2):

This will most likely not work in the browser. Check out some other threads on stackoverflow for this:

- [How do I update FB Status using Python & GraphAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372528/how-do-i-update-fb-status-using-python-graphapi)
- [Posting to Facebook wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16668498/posting-to-facebook-wall)

Also, check out google, there are many tutorials and frameworks for using the Facebook API with Python.