# Using Selenium(Python) for PrtSc Function

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to be able to screenshot a page and send that file in an email. For example, if manually i screenshot this page using the PrtSc function on the keyboard and I go to my email text box all i have to do is CONTROL V to paste it there and send. Is there a way I was do something like this using selenium?

I can currently screenshot using this function

> driver.save_screenshot('screenie.png')

However, it doesn't do what I want it to. It just screenshots and saves the file in the folder.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `.save_screenshot()` does exactly what it is supposed to do - takes a screenshot of the browser page and saves it in an image file.

Now, if you want to further send this file as an attachment over email, you can use `smtplib`:

- [How to send email attachments with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362600/how-to-send-email-attachments-with-python)

Comment: What if I wanted to screenshot and paste and send on like facebook. Is there a way to do that automatically using selenium.

Comment: @sa7 you can do facebook posting via `facebook-sdk` graph api, sample here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43476182/771848. Hope that's what you meant.

Comment: @sa7 you can, of course, navigate to facebook in your selenium automated browser, log in and post, but that's a lot of overhead.

Comment: Thanks a lot @alecxe. I also want to be able to send a screenshot as a message on facebook. is that also possible?