# how to post in facebook using selenium webdriver and python

Tags: python, facebook, selenium

I writen this code to post in facebook group from desktop program  but it didnnot work.
I'm using python and selenium webdriver in this script.

Can someone help me?

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import webDriverWait 

import unittest

class post(unittest.Testcase):

    def setUp(self):
            self.driver = webdriver.Firefox
            self.driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/<grouplink>")

    def test_shar(self):
        driver = self.driver
        grouppost  = "test"
        textid     = "xhpc_message_text"
        buttonid   = ".//*[@id='u_jsonp_25_s']/div/div[5]/div/ul/li[2]/button"
        fblogopath = "(//a[contains(@href, 'logo')])[1]"

        textfiledelemnt = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(textid))
        sharebotton     = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(buttonid)

        textfiledelemnt.clear()
        textfiledelemnt.send_keys(grouppost)
        buttonid.click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(fblogopath)

    def tearDown(self):
            self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: In what way did it not work? How far did it get? And do you need to be signed in to Facebook to post to this group?

Comment: yes i signed in facebook its didnnot work copletley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you not to rely to WebDriver for purpose such as one you mention.

Use [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api), here are two good examples:

1) [How do I update FB Status using Python & GraphAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372528/how-do-i-update-fb-status-using-python-graphapi)

2) [Posting to Facebook wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16668498/posting-to-facebook-wall)

Comment: This doesn't address how to post to Groups.

Comment: It's pretty much the same, just use Graph API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/group

Answer (score 1):

```
def postInGroup(driver, group_url, text):
    driver.get(group_url)

    driver.find_element_by_name("xc_message").send_keys(text)
    driver.find_element_by_name("view_post").click()
```

This will work for mbasic version of Facebook i.e group_url = 'https://mbasic.facebook.com/your-group-link'

The rest is same.